# Shell code to run Google Chrome from an UNIX terminal at MAC OS X

Tags: unix, macos-mojave, iterm

Is there some code I could use to run Google Chrome from terminal?
My idea is to save some frequent links saved  as alias to check them from time to time.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/ is a better forum for this question.  StackOverflow is meant for programming questions while AskDifferent focuses on general MacOS questions. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/83630/create-a-terminal-command-to-open-file-with-chrome.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here lies the command to make an alias as I meant to create:

```
alias alias_name='open -a "Google Chrome" http://websitetobeopened.com'
```